# I want to know which sentence is correct

Tags: past-tense

Which question in is past simple tense grammatically correct?

> Who **called** you?

or

> Who **did call** you?

Answer (score 2):

In

> Who **did call** you?

**did call** is *past emphatic*.  It is used to *emphasize the action of calling*.  This sentence is interrogative and the subject is not known; therefore, emphasis seems out of place. 
The verb form would be correct, however, if written as an emphatic statement:

> He **did call** you.

In the other provided sentence,

> Who **called** you?

the tense, **past**, works with the interrogative nature of the sentence.  This sentence is *valid*.

Answer (score 1):

The first option is correct because this instance is conveying a single, completed action. While I don't think the second sentence is incorrect grammatically, it wouldn't be regularly used in normal conversation.